# Evaluating Jacobi's symbol using Eisenstein's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The algorithm is described as follow,

> Eisenstein proposed the following algorithm for computing the Jacobi symbol $(a|n)$ where $a$ and $n$ are odd numbers. Write
>   $n = aq + er$ where $q = \lfloor n/a \rfloor$ if this is even, or $q = \lfloor n/a \rfloor + 1$ otherwise, and $e = \pm 1$ accordingly.
>   Then $r$ is odd, and you can use the quadratic reciprocity law and the formula for $(-1|r)$ to continue by replacing the pair $n,a$ with 
>   the pair $a, r$.

I understand the Euler's algorithm (division), and got it to work correctly. Unfortunately, I have no idea how this algorithm works. Furthermore, what's the end condition of this algorithm? My guess was $r \neq 1$ is the end condition, but the result was completely wrong. 
An example to illustrate this algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
This is my solution, written in C#

```
public int eisensteinAlgo( int a, int n ) {
            int parity = 1;
            int q = 0;
            int epsilon;
            int r = 0;
            while ( ( n % a ) == 0 ) {
                q = n / a;
                if ( ( q % 2 ) == 1 ) {
                    q += 1;
                    epsilon = -1;
                }
                else {
                    epsilon = 1;
                }
                r = n - ( a * q );
                r *= epsilon;
                parity *= ( int )Math.Pow( -1.0, ( r - 1 ) / 2 );
                n = a;
                a = r;
            }
            return parity;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Notes on your code: **a.** It might be better to use `(q & 1) == 1` instead of `( q % 2 ) == 1` **b.** `n - ( a * q )` is just `n % a` all over again; why are you computing it again? **c.** Exponentiation is slow; figure out a conditional to replace your computation for `parity` (which I'll leave as an exercise).

Comment: @J.M.: Many thanks for your comments. However, my rule of thumb is to get the right code first, then optimize it later. Because I think writing the right code in the first place is often much harder than optimize it.

Comment: "get the right code first, then optimize it later." - of course. :)

Comment: Thanks for the agreement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduction step is simply to apply quadratic reciprocity in order to rewrite $(a|n)$ to $\pm (n|a)\:,\:$ then reduce $n$ modulo $a\:$ in a way that the remainder stays odd (by forcing the quotient $q\:$ to be even). The algorithm terminates when $a$ divides $n\:,$ with the result being either the accumulated sign (if $ a=1)\:,$ or else $\:0\:$ (if $ a>1)\:.\:$ The choice of odd remainder eliminates the need to pull out factors of $2\:.$ But one pays a price for this algorithmic simplification since it makes the algorithm less efficient.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I was trying to solve other problems. First of all, thanks a lot for your answer. But I don't understand how the result were calculated. Do we calculate $(-1|r)$ each time using the formula $(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ and then multiply it with the result?

Comment: Yes, you can keep a $\:\pm 1\:$ sign "accumulator" multiplying the symbol during the calculation. If you're stuck then show your work so we can see precisely where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I posted my solution in C# since I don't know which language you're most familiar with. However, the semantic meaning should be straightforward. Thanks.

Comment: I've just figured out the program I wrote above was incorrect for several cases. I got the reverse sign, would you mind taking a look at my code?  Thanks in advance.